# can we replace Link register with program counter?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Suppose a Program P contains a branch Instruction which will branch to a **Subroutine S** .IN Subroutine S , It will execute instructions and will reach its return Instruction where it will found the Next instruction to be Executed in the P(or return to Program P).

Now My question is that if there is no Nested Subroutine ,then can't we simply use Program counter instead of using Link Register (for storing the next instruction to be executed in P).As after reaching Return instruction in subroutine ,it will simply get address to be executed next from Program counter.

Note -: i know it will create problem in case of nested Subroutine ,i am just asking for single subroutine.

Comment: The PC needs to hold the address of each instruction being executed inside the subroutine.  If the PC was pointing to the return address, that's where the CPU would be executing.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..!!! i got it @peter

Comment: @PeterCordes i have one more doubt  that how many program counter are there in a cpu? i mean if there would be a single PC then only one program will be executed at a time!!

Comment: It's a counter.  It counts progress through the program: i.e. the address of the instruction currently being executed.  Logically, only one instruction is being executed at a time (on a single core).  In reality, a superscalar pipelined CPU has many instructions in flight.

Comment: But I think what you're really mixed up about is how an OS runs multiple processes on a single CPU.  The program counter is saved / restored along with the rest of the architectural state on context switches.  (Google those terms).

Comment: Regarding OS i know the concept ...you mean context switching ..??right?? i am asking form architectural point of view

Comment: Don't mix software (OS) threads and HW threads. A CPU with N cores and M threads per core will have M*N physical copies of the PC, allowing all HW threads to run in parallel. On context switch, the relevant PC will be replaced by some value that was swapped out earlier